# FSPathMakeRef and FSRefMakePath are deprecated in OS X 10.8, what are the alternatives?

Tags: macos, deprecated, osx-mountain-lion

I've noticed that `FSPathMakeRef()` and `FSRefMakePath()` are now deprecated in OS X 10.8.

I have some code that uses them to find the canonical case for a path, e.g. if passed "/USeRs" it will return "/Users".

Why have these and other related functions been deprecated, and what non-deprecated API should be used now instead to provide equivalent functionality?

Comment: OS X's filesystem is case insensitive, unless you format it specifically as case sensitive.

Comment: HFS+ is, 'by default', case-insensitive but case-preserving. It can be formatted to be case-sensitive, and OS X itself works fine with case-sensitive and case-insensitive filesystems.

Comment: I believe FSPathMakeRef ignores case.  The version of unix that runs OS X is indeed case sensitive, but the Finder and a HFS+ file-related functions are not (unless the partition has been formatted to be case-sensitive).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `NSURL` to store both ordinary paths and file reference paths.

From the [File Manager documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/File_Manager/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000107-AppendixA) (Appendix A: Deprecated File Manager Functions):

> **FSMakeFSRefUnicode**
>
> Constructs an FSRef for a file or directory, given a parent directory and a Unicode name. (Deprecated in OS X v10.8. Use NSURL or CFURL APIs instead. To track the behavior of file-system items by ID, create file reference URLs using fileReferenceURL or CFURLCreateFileReferenceURL.)

From what I can tell, Apple chose to deprecate the `FSRef` type entirely, favouring file reference URLs (which look like `file:///.file/id=6571367.39068/`) instead.

If you want to canonicalize a string path, you can do the following using non-deprecated APIs:

```
NSString *canonicalPath = [[[NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/USeRs"] fileReferenceURL] path];
```

Comment: Okay, but what if I want to save the alias information to core-data? The idea is to be able to find the file in case it is moved or deleted.